# How to control the distance between a Gtk.Frame and Gtk.HBox inside?

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk3

Consider this example:
[image]

You can see in this window, is a `Gtk.Frame`, named "Coefficients". Inside of that is a `Gtk.HBox`. Inside the `Gtk.HBox`, are ten `Gtk.Scale`s.

What I'd like to do, is control the padding between the `Gtk.Frame`, and anything that's inside, effectively the `Gtk.HBox`, or rather, the `Gtk.Scale`s inside of that. How would I go about that?

In case this is important, I'm using Python3 and Gtk3.

Comment: `pack_start(..., padding=...)` ?

Comment: Ok, I assume I'd use that on the HBox?

Comment: I didn't use `.pack_start()`, I used `.add()`, is that a problem?

Comment: `.add()` doesn't have option `padding=` and I don't know if there is method to add `padding` after using `.add()`

Comment: in [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/2.24/class-gtkbox.html) (for Gtk2 but it works with Gtk3 too) you can see also `HBox(..., spacing=...)`

Comment: I tried `Gtk.HBox(spacing=50)` didn't do anything. I also tried to set the spacing using `hbox.set_spacing(50)`, didn't do anything either.

Comment: create minimal working code so we could run it and test some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have made progress going about it a quite different way, however there seem to be inconsistencies.

I defined a CSS with the following contents (`self` is a `Gtk.Window`):

```
self._css = b"""
    #coeff_container {
        padding: 20pt;
    }
"""
```

The Window this is displayed in is composed like this:

`Gtk.Window` > `Gtk.Frame` > `Gtk.HBox` > ten `Gtk.Scale`s

```
self._hbox = Gtk.HBox()
```

The `Gtk.HBox` has the property "name" set like this:

```
self._hbox.set_name("coeff_container")
self._hbox.set_spacing(20)
```

Now, as you can see, I've set the spacing to 20, but the padding property is set in the CSS.

Applying the CSS is done as follows:

```
self._style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
self._style_provider.load_from_data(self._css)

Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen( Gdk.Screen.get_default(),
                                          self._style_provider,
                                          Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATIONS )
```

I cannot set the `spacing` property in CSS, it only works with `.set_spacing(int)`, on the other hand, I can't set `padding` *not* in CSS, it is quite confusing like that.